# Language-specific Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-layout

I just don't find a German language download for Ubuntu Desktop.
Isn't there any, and the language has to be set during the install?
I'm installing it in VMWare Workstation, and it doesn't offer me a language selection.
I always end up with an English-interfaced Ubuntu.

How would I install or set Ubuntu to German with German keyboard layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the language is to be set during the installation but then it can be changed at any time in the installed system.

The system's language is defined in System Settings > Language... . Ubuntu picks up the first in the list. Support for additional languages (and respective font when needed) can be added without changing the default language. Install as many as you need/want.

Comment: Word of caution: language keyboard isn't set at once, if you are on some foreign layout, you may be setting passwords (for the LUKS encryption, for instance) with the default Qwerty layout. Stick to simple and layout-agnostic passwords at that stage, and change them once the installation is complete.

Comment: @xenoid Indeed.